# integrating camera and email

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to develop an application that will automatically send an email as soon as an image is captured by the camera.
can anybody suggest some ideas regarding this???

Comment: You might start by getting an apple dev account and looking at the camera api and messaging docs

Answer (score 0):

Really easy to do.  The 
[Iphone developer's cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321555457) has some "recipes" that will get you pointed in the right direction on how to do this.